# Low power, quiet and semi affordable domain controller for distributed environment use

Tags: hardware, domain-controller

I work in a distibuted environment, and I would like to setup a domain controller. I don't really want a full blown desktop running full time, just to handle requests from 1 client pc in my home office.

I was wondering do you get any specialized boxes which are specifically used as windows based domain controllers, something like those small modern NAS servers?

I need real domain functionality for testing, so it can't be light weight or watered down.

Might sound a bit off the wall, but I would like to just have a device like a router, I could rdc in when required, but it would only be a Windows 2008 r2 domain controller. And support upgrading to future versions.

Does such a solution exists. I don't want my study to be turned into a server room. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem like a good candidate for an HP ProLiant Microserver....

See:
http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF31a/15351-15351-4237916-4237918-4237917-4248009.html

and

http://h30423.www3.hp.com/?fr_story=c080b0e57b3504e624b5e1e2dbc8122de745469c&rf=sitemap

It's pretty tiny, has four hot-swap bays and is more than robust enough for your application. A good number of people have used them as Solaris ZFS NAS appliances. There's also a [thread for owners of the device detailing their experiences here](http://www.hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1555868).

[image]

Comment: That server literally dropped out of the sky from God :)

Comment: Do you think these specs can keep up with advanced testing AD - Report smallest size savings for office work and for basic home use, D510 CPU Intel Atom 1.66GHz dual-core, 320GB SATA HDD, 2GB DDR2, VGA int. GMA 3150

Comment: That server is more powerful than the DC machines that I had in my first Win2k domain. You'll be fine.